# Are there any sources to build Flutter online?

Tags: flutter, build

I have a flutter project. I am making an Android app but since my system is too slow it get's stuck everytime I make a build. Am using `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` to build the app.

Is there anyway to make a build locally by optimizing something or any place online where I can build using a github repo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about building a production app, some honorable mentions are:

- [Codemagic](https://blog.codemagic.io/getting-started-with-codemagic/), dedicated to Flutter
- [Bitrise](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/getting-started/getting-started-with-flutter-apps/)
- [Appcircle](https://appcircle.io/blog/guide-to-automated-mobile-ci-cd-for-flutter-projects-with-appcircle/)
- [GitHub Actions](https://medium.com/flutter-community/automating-publishing-your-flutter-apps-to-google-play-using-github-actions-2f67ac582032) *(disclaimer: I am the author of this one)*
- or virtually any other CI/CD service